# C++ "atomic_compare_exchange_strong" apply to non-atomic variable

Tags: c++11

```
std::shared_ptr<int> node;
int *expect = new int(1);
int *desire = new int(2);
atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&node, &expect, desire)
```

What makes this code run as I image? the "node" is not modified by atomic
What conditions does "node" need to meet?
I think volatile modification is needed in C, but I don’t know what is needed in C++.

I want to ask the apply conditions of atomic_compare_exchange_strong

Comment: They have [explicit specialization for shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic). Also note: `These functions are typically implemented using mutexes...` - so, it is more for convenience rather than for extra performance: "atomic" does not mean "lock-free"